# SQL query to update 1000 records

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have created 1000 records with ID as sequence Id. Now, I have list of 1000 unique codes, which I need to assign to each record.

Like this:

[image]

I am looking for suggestions to achieve it using SQL script.

Comment: Start over and insert the unique codes and id at the same time.

Comment: @jarlh At this point, I dont have access to the codes. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: If you don't have access to the codes, then  how are you going to assign them?

Comment: In addition to the question by @grootygroot ( he beat me to it) , even when you have access to the codes, how do you determine which code is assigned to which id?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name codes will be given to another team, I have to provide update script for them to update the codes

Comment: @EdStevens that order doesn't matter. but each id should be assigned a unique code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO destination_table dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWNUM rn,
         value
  FROM   your_codes_table
) src
ON ( src.rn = dst.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET code = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( id, code ) VALUES ( destination_table__id__seq.NEXTVAL, src.value );
```

However, that will increment the sequence for every row updated and inserted and this may not be what you want.

The simplest way is to delete the existing rows (without codes) from your destination table and the delete the sequence you are basing the `id` values on and then recreate the sequence (to reset the sequence back to its starting value):

```sql
DELETE FROM destination_table;
DROP SEQUENCE destination_table__id__seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE destination_table__id__seq;
```

and insert the rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO destination_table ( id, code )
SELECT destination_table__id__seq.NEXTVAL,
       value
FROM   your_codes_table
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ca1e2f052a35236eb36fac8766d9fa6)

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `row_number()`?

```
select code, row_number() over (order by code) as id
from t;
```